# why doesn't html.textbox generate data-val attributes while html.textboxFor does?

Tags: html, jquery, validation, razor, data-annotations

I have a form in a razor page where im implementing clientside validation using jquery, jquery unobtrusive and jquery validation alongside dataannotaions to validate the model.

Using strongly typed textboxes i get the data-val attributes that i need for displaying errors using ValidationMessage() method.

HOWEVER when i use the loosely typed textbox the data-val attributes does not get generated, why is this?

it is important that it works for Html.Textbox() since im using a more complex data structure and need to define specifik names for each element in the list.

loosly typed textbox and validationMessage:

[image]

Generated html:

[image]

Strongly typed textbox and validationMessage:

[image]

Generated html:

[image]

we can clearly see the data-val attributes here

The name field is built up like this (where key is a guid uniqe to each item in the list):

[image]

how come the data-val attributes don't appear with loosly typed textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

I think i know the answer, since it is strongly typed we have information about the dataannotation in the model, whereas the loosley type just generates html from a name.